# Find out specific weblogic process running

Tags: java, unix, grep, weblogic

I need to find the weblogic instances which are up and running.
 My unix box has both java 5 and 6 and have more than one weblogic domain.
 I need to kill the java instance of one particular domain.
 Here is the out put for ps -ef | grep java command, but couldn't figure out which PID is for which domain instance.
 Please help.

```
 ps -ef | grep java
weblogic 16374 21956  0 23:30:33 ?        1:00 /app/bea/jdk1.6.0_33/bin/java -Xmx1024m -Xms256m -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///
    root 22733 22732  0   Apr 29 ?       123:29 ../jre/bin/java -da -server -Dtw.server=false -Djava.security.manager=com.tripw
weblogic 16862 21956  0 23:31:13 ?        2:04 /app/bea/jdk1.6.0_33/bin/java -Xmx1024m -Xms256m -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///
weblogic  8445 21956  0 18:32:33 ?        3:29 /app/bea/jdk1.6.0_33/jre/bin/java -Dweblogic.log.StdoutSeverity=Debug -Dweblogi
weblogic 16529 21956  0   May 29 ?       88:28 /app/bea/home/jdk150_15/bin/java -server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=25
weblogic 15357  5681  0 00:07:14 pts/4    0:00 grep java
weblogic 14088 21956  0 23:28:00 ?        0:33 /app/bea/jdk1.6.0_33/bin/java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///app/bea/weblogic12c
weblogic  2129 21956  0 23:13:41 ?       24:14 /app/bea/jdk1.6.0_33/bin/java -server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: do you know if the one which you want to kill is using Java 5 or 6 ?above 16529 is on java 5, others are all java 6

Comment: it seems that your ps output was somehow truncated? here I can see which server in ps output, same as @Eng showed. also you could just `ps -ef|grep [w]eblogic`

Comment: try ps -ef | grep yourDomainName

Comment: Worst case scenario - you can bring up jconsole and connect to the server pids you have running. `jconsole pid` and then if you go to the VM Summary tab you'll see the entire VM arguments, classpath, etc

Comment: The one I have to kill is Java 6 only. I can see that the output is truncated. Let me try with those options

Answer (score 5):

There mightbe possibility that your ps output is truncated by default.

Like  on solaris box the ps output will be truncated like above  in that case you can use below command

/usr/ucb/ps awwx|grep java|grep -i Admin -This will show Admin Server

/usr/ucb/ps awwx|grep java|grep -i "Managed_server_Name" - For Managed server

/usr/ucb/ps awwx|grep java|grep -i Node - For Node manager process

To identify by pid by domain you can use command like

/usr/ucb/ps awwx|grep java|grep -i "DOmain_name" |grep -i "Managed_server_name"

You can check domain name and managed server name using Admin console

Comment: This syntax helped for shutdown of failed WebLogic node on Solaris10

Answer (score 1):

Nice way to see just the weblogic processes in ps with their **weblogic server names**:

```
ps -aef | grep javaee | grep Dweblogic.Name | sed -e 's/\-Dweblogic\.Name/WLPROC/g' -e 's/\-[^ ]*\s//g' -e 's/\/[^ ]*\s//g'
```

Here is an example output:

> userX    10611 10608  5 05:34 pts   00:03:13 WLPROC=AnalyticProviderServices0 weblogic.Server
>   userX    20918 20915  0 May26 pts   00:18:28 WLPROC=AdminServer weblogic.Server

Answer (score 0):

Use `jdk` instead:

```
ps -ef | grep jdk
```

The result would look like this:

> 1005         8383           31663           2 Jun04 ?        00:27:49 /weblogic103/jdk160_05/jre/bin/java -Dweblogic.Name=**AdminServer** ... etc

Comment: Im getting the same output only. Not seeing any server names. May be bcz it uses a configuration file for start up ?

Answer (score 0):

**In Unix**, use -efl parameters on 'ps' command. Then play with the power of grep as you need.

Below command will display the java processes, running for all the domains and also with your weblogic user.

```
ps -efl | grep weblogic | grep java | grep Dweblogic.Name | grep -v grep
```

Answer (score 0):

go to domain home, under
cd u01/app/oracle/wls1st/finance/servers/ServerName/tmp

(ServerName is your instance name , if its AdminServer give AdminServer then go to tmp folder)

where you can findout lok file, AdminServer.lok , its shows the running process id of AdminServer

fuser -f AdminServer.lok

you can get running process id of AdminServer

then kill -9 processID

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
ps -ef | grep Middle
```

That will list the process running from the directory middleware:

```
oracle@solaris2:~$ ps -ef | grep Middle
oracle  4998  2728   0 21:32:37 ? 0:00 /bin/sh/u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/ETPortalDEV_domain/bin/sta
oracle  2267  1488   0 20:12:06 ? 0:00 /bin/sh/u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/sites_domain/bin/startWebL
root  1488     1   0 20:05:26 ?   0:00 su - oracle -c /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/sites_domain/bin/st
oracle   480 29078   0 12:00:46 pts/2       0:00 grep Middle
```